# TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server --This wizard will close because it encountered the following error

Tags: settings, environment

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server
>
> This wizard will close because it encountered the following error:
>
> For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com:80/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=16.0.5395.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.WizardFrameworkErrorSR&EvtID=UncaughtException&LinkId=20476
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.data: Column 'InvariantName' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is already present. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config line 157) (System.Configuration)
>
> Column 'InvariantName' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is already present. (System.Data)

I am expecting a solution of my problem